# Check if a specific user did a command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a command that I could use in every server, but when others use "-help" it doesn't show in the list of commands. I know the normal way to do this would be:

```
if ctx.author.id == myID:
  #do some code
```

But if I do it like this, the user can still see that the command exists when using "-help". Is there any way to get around this? Is there a
@commands.command
@commands.is_user(myID)
?

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options, you can either make a check, make a decorator, or make a global check:

1.

```py
def is_user(ctx):
    return not ctx.author.id == myID

@bot.command()
@commands.check(is_user)
async def foo(ctx):
    ...
```

2. decorator

```py
def is_user(func):
    def wrapper(ctx):
        return not ctx.author.id == myID
    return commands.check(wrapper)

@bot.command()
@is_user
async def foo(ctx):
    ...
```

3. global check

```py
@bot.check
async def is_user(ctx):
    return not ctx.author.id == myID
```

If a check returns `False`, `commands.CheckFailure` is going to be raised, you can make an error handler and send something like "You can't use this command" or whatever.

Reference:

- [`commands.check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.check)
- [`commands.Bot.check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Bot.check)
- [`commands.CheckFailure`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.CheckFailure)

Answer (score 0):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#help-commands

Help commands can have a `hidden` attribute, which makes them not show up in the help command.

```py
@commands.command(..., hidden=True)
def my_command(...):
    ...
```