# Send a different message if specific id uses the command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make this command so that when the specific id uses it, it will send another message.

```py
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def ship(self, ctx):
        user = choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
        em = Embed(
            title = 'شیپ های زیبا',
            description = f'{ctx.message.author.mention} X {user.mention}',
            colour = ctx.guild.me.top_role.colour
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: Consider to check your question, it is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

To tackle this problem, my strongest recommendation is to use an `if-else` statement, where you check if the `ctx.author.id` is the same as a set id that you provide. Do have a look at the code snippet below, along with an image of a working example.

```py
@commands.command()
async def ship(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == 000000: # replace this with the user's id
        # code runs if these two ids are equal to each other
        # do something here

    # if you want to use multiple users, use an elif statement
    elif ctx.author.id == 0000: # replace this with another user's id
        # do something here

    else: # 'else' if the author is none of these ids
        # do something else
```

[image: Image example of the above code]

**Other Links**:

- [How to check if message was sent by certain user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206940/how-to-check-if-message-was-sent-by-certain-user-discord-py/52207112) - Stackoverflow
- [Check if a specific user did a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365886/check-if-a-specific-user-did-a-command-discord-py) - Stackoverflow
- [Python conditions (`if`, `elif`, `else`)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) - Stackoverflow

---

**Edit** (answering question in comments)

To my knowledge, a good way to get a random user that isn't the author is by using a `while True` loop. With every iteration, the bot would check if the randomly chosen user is the author, and if it is not, the bot will break the loop and send the user. Otherwise, it would continue looping until the user is not equal to the author. Do view the code snippet below.

```py
while True:
    user = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)
    if user == ctx.author:
        continue # Restarts the loop
    break # Ends the loop

await ctx.send(user)
```

[image: Above code snippet working as expected]

Comment: tnx but how can I to bot don't tag the Specific idis?

Comment: @PEKAH what do you mean by this?

Comment: this command tags a random member and I mean like when someone else use this command bot don't tag dose idis that i wrote.

Comment: @PEKAH sorry for the delay. Do view the edited answer, thanks.